# How to save breakpoints using the Delphi IDE?

Tags: delphi, breakpoints

How can I save breakpoints using the Delphi IDE? I only know how to store the settings in a `.dsk` file.

I am using Delphi 2007.

Comment: The IDE's settings are saved in the .dsk file, so that is how you store them *via IDE*. I turned on *Tools->Options->Environment Options->Autosave options->Project desktop* and I have persistent bookmarks (bookmarks that are set when the project is saved are still there when the project is reopened).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm  assuming from your mention of the .Dsk file that you are aware that the breakpoints are stored in there, but want to save them yourself for some reason.  Of course, the easiest method of getting a list of saved breakpoints is simply to read them from the .Dsk file, but that assumes that it has been saved to disk, which usually
occurs when you close the project file.

You can write your own IDE plug-in to get a list of currently-set breakpoints
and save them in any way you want.  The minimalist example below shows how to do this - see the `GetBreakpoints` method for details.  To use this in the IDE, you would create a new package which *requires*
DesignIde.Dcp.  Make sure that the output directory for the .Bpl file is either where
your 3rd-party .Bpls are stored on or is on your path.  You can then install the
package in the IDE vie `Install packages` from the IDE's menu.

As you can see, it works by using the `BorlandIDEServices` interface in the ToolsAPI units to get an `IOTADebuggerServices` interface, and then uses that to iterate its `SourceBkpts` list and saves a number of properties of each `IOTASourceBreakpoint` in that list.

Note that

- You can also retrieve a list of `address breakpoints` and save those in a similar fashion.
- Both kinds of breakpoint interface in ToolsAPI have property setters as well as getters, so you could modify existing breakpoints in code and conceivably create new ones.

Code

```
uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms, Dialogs,
  StdCtrls, ToolsApi;

type
  TBreakpointSaveForm = class(TForm)
    Memo1: TMemo;
    btnGetBreakpoints: TButton;
    procedure btnGetBreakpointsClick(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
  private
  protected
  public
    procedure GetBreakpoints;
  end;

var
  BreakpointSaveForm: TBreakpointSaveForm;

procedure Register;

implementation

{$R *.DFM}

procedure TBreakpointSaveForm.GetBreakpoints;
var
  DebugSvcs: IOTADebuggerServices;

  procedure SaveBreakpoint(BreakPoint : IOTASourceBreakpoint);
  begin
    Memo1.Lines.Add('File:      ' + Breakpoint.FileName);
    Memo1.Lines.Add('LineNo:    ' + IntToStr(Breakpoint.LineNumber));
    Memo1.Lines.Add('Passcount: ' + IntToStr(Breakpoint.Passcount));
    Memo1.Lines.Add('');
  end;

  procedure SaveBreakpoints;
  var
    i : Integer;
    BreakPoint : IOTASourceBreakpoint;
  begin
    Memo1.Lines.Add('Source breakpoint count : '+ IntToStr(DebugSvcs.GetSourceBkptCount));
    for i := 0 to DebugSvcs.GetSourceBkptCount - 1 do begin
      Breakpoint := DebugSvcs.SourceBkpts[i];
      SaveBreakpoint(Breakpoint);
    end;
  end;

begin
  if not Supports(BorlandIDEServices, IOTADebuggerServices, DebugSvcs) then begin
    ShowMessage('Failed to get IOTADebuggerServices interface');
    exit;
  end;
  Memo1.Lines.Clear;
  SaveBreakpoints;
end;

procedure Register;
begin
end;

initialization
  BreakpointSaveForm := TBreakpointSaveForm.Create(Application);
  BreakpointSaveForm.Show;

finalization

  if Assigned(BreakpointSaveForm) then
    BreakpointSaveForm.Free;
end.

procedure TBreakpointSaveForm.btnGetBreakpointsClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  GetBreakpoints;
end;
```